# Possible to send an email from SendGrid & React.js without a back-end?

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I have a React.js app that I am hosting on a cPanel that does not allow a back-end within the application.  Wondering if I can get sendgrid to work without the back-end?  Has anyone gotten this to work previously?

I currently get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' from origin ' 
    https://angelospizzaharvard.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response 
    to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control- 
    Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not 
    equal to the supplied origin. 


Have the server send the header with a valid 
    value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode 
    to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
    Navbar.js:427 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: It should definitely be possible, but really not recommended at all since you would need to expose your email server auth credentials to the frontend, which is a big no-no

Comment: Bill, 
 What if I keep the email server login credentials hidden in a .env file?

Comment: @Eric K. It will still be exposed since it needs to be sent along the request.

Comment: @EricK.the .env file only keeps the secret values out of your git repo, they are still exposed to the frontend in production

Answer (score 2):

From this link [sendgrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/), it seems that it could only be called from a back-end server.

Comment: Thanks, Shmili.  Do you know of any other technologies that might allow for email from a form in a front-end-only application?

Comment: @Eric K. I have used `formspree.io` before however the free version has some severe limitations. (it redirects a user on submit).